# Reversing a string in place without using iteration in C

Tags: c, strings, array

This is function for reversing a string in C using recursive calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revert(char* left, char* right) { // Should I pass char* like I'm doing now or are char** a better idea?
    if(left == right) return;

    char *ll = left; char* rr = right;

    char tmp = right[0];
    right[0] = left[0];
    left[0] = tmp;
    revert(++ll,--rr);
}

int main() {
    char rev_string[] = "Some teststring";
    printf("%s\n", rev_string);
    revert(&rev_string[0],&rev_string[strlen(rev_string)-1]);//rev_string[strlen(rev_string)-1]);
    printf("%s\n", rev_string); 
    return 0;
}
```

Can it be simplified? Can anything be written better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp) is absolutely right on all counts.
In addition,
since the updated values of `++left` and `--right` are not needed,
I would prefer to use `left + 1` and `right - 1`.

It's inconvenient and error prone for callers to set the end pointer.
I recommend a wrapper function that takes a single `char*` parameter,
and sets the end pointer correctly, for example:

```
void revert_recursive(char* left, char* right) {
    if (left < right) {
        char tmp = *right;
        *right = *left;
        *left = tmp;
        revert_recursive(left + 1, right - 1);
    }
}

void revert(char* str) { 
    revert_recursive(str, str + strlen(str) - 1);
}
```

To make the program easier to play around with,
I recommend to make the `main` function work with command line arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int i;
    char* arg;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        arg = argv[i];
        printf("%s\n", arg);
        revert(arg);
        printf("%s\n", arg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Finally,
in the question you described the task as *reversing a string*,
but called the method "revert" instead of "reverse".
The latter would be better, as "reverting" means more like "undoing".

Comment: Thanks, but why exactly is `left + 1` and `right - 1` better than `++left` and `--right`? Wouldn't there be new values created in both cases?

Comment: In this particular example both yield the same result. But strictly speaking there's no need to modify the values of these local variables, so why do it then. Every operation in a program is a potential bug. So if an operation is unnecessary, then it's effectively a net negative, so it makes sense to not do it. Although the difference here may seem negligible, this is a matter of principle, neglecting it can lead to bad habits that are hard to cure

Answer (score 2):

- There is a bug. `Some teststring` contains an odd number of characters, therefore a `left == right` condition is eventually hit. For an even-length string, it would never be satisfied. You should test for `left < right` instead.
- There is absolutely no need to reassign `left, right` to `ll, rr`. `revert(++left, --right)` works as good.

  To clear the possible confusion (see comments) this is what I meant:

  ```
  if (left < right) {
      swap_values(left, right);
      revert(++left, --right);
  }
  ```

Comment: I think you meant `left > right`.

Comment: @REACHUS Almost. I was automatically thinking for a positive case (`if (condition) { do_stuff(); }`). For a negative case, you need to test for `left >= right`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify by using a length instead of `right`.  Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *s, size_t len) {
    if (len <= 1) return;

    char tmp = s[len-1];
    s[len-1] = s[0];
    s[0]     = tmp;
    reverse(s+1, len-2);
}

int main() {
    char rev_string[] = "Some teststring";
    printf("%s\n", rev_string);
    reverse(rev_string, strlen(rev_string));
    printf("%s\n", rev_string); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution uses tail-recursion. Some compilers can optimize this into a simple jump. Others will create a full function call in every case. That quickly causes a stack overflow and limits the length of strings you can reverse.

It would be better to use a while or for loop instead of recursion.

Comment: I know that iterative approach would be better, I was just doing it as an exercise with pointers and recursion. Do you know how can I see how did a specific compiler optimize my code?